# ngDisabled not working for radio group bound no nested model - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, radio-button, disabled-input

I am trying to implement two way data binding using a model that is an array of objects in this format:

```
 $rootScope["bBoxProps"] =[{
                        "bType": "sBusinessType",
                        "id":"sBusinessType",
                        "title":"business",
                        "options":[
                                    {
                                      "optId":"nyi",
                                      "name":"nyi",
                                      "isSelected":true,
                                      "isDisabled":false,
                                      "isInvalid":false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "optId":"local",
                                      "name":"local",
                                      "isSelected":false,
                                      "isDisabled":false,
                                      "isInvalid":false
                                    }
                                  ],
                        "disabled":false,
                        "invalid":false
                      },{...},{...}];
```

To a radio group of two radio buttons within an ngRepeat as shown below:

```
<div class="buyBox" id="{{bBox.id}}" ng-repeat="bBox in bBoxProps" ng-class="{disabledBb: bBox.disabled, invalidBb: bBox.invalid}">
            <div class="bbTitle"><h3>{{bBox.title | uppercase}}</h3></div>
            <div class="bbSelect">
                <div class="bbSelectTop bbSelectOpt">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[0])" ng-checked="bBox.options[0].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[0].isDisabled==true" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[0].isInvalid}"/>
                    <label for="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="bbLabel"><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[0].name | uppercase}}</div></label>
                </div>
                <div class="bbSelectBottom bbSelectOpt">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[1])" ng-checked="bBox.options[1].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[1].isDisabled==true" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[1].isInvalid}"/>
                    <label for="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="bbLabel"><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[1].name | uppercase}}</div></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Everything is working fine, except the "isDisabled" suboption is not binding to the radio button. When I set the flag to false through JavaScript, it does not reflect on the HTML and the radio button remains unchanged.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with the implementation or is something wrong with ngDisabled?

Comment: Hi, please have a look here http://jsbin.com/hefeb/2/edit it looks like everything is fine ?

Comment: Yup.. it works like that. Weird...Found the solution anyway..Updated as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.. added ng-value and ng-model:

```
<div class="buyBox" id="{{bBox.id}}" ng-repeat="bBox in bBoxProps" ng-class="{disabledBb: bBox.disabled, invalidBb: bBox.invalid}">
            <div class="bbTitle"><h3>{{bBox.title | uppercase}}</h3></div>
            <div class="bbSelect">
                <div class="bbSelectTop bbSelectOpt">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[0])" ng-checked="bBox.options[0].isSelected==true" ng-model="bBox.options[0].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[0].isDisabled" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[0].isInvalid}" ng-value="true"/>
                    <label for="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="bbLabel"><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[0].name}}</div></label>
                </div>
                <div class="buyOr">OR</div>
                <div class="bbSelectBottom bbSelectOpt">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[1])" ng-checked="bBox.options[1].isSelected==true" ng-model="bBox.options[1].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[1].isDisabled" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[1].isInvalid}" ng-value="true"/>
                    <label for="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="bbLabel"><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[1].name}}</div></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```